# Как вставить тег в строку сообщения на форуме?

Tags: html

Есть сайт, где когда я отправляю сообщения, то в редакторе нет кнопки "вставить ссылку". Я решила это дело обойти вставив `<a> моя ссылка </a>` в нужное место в моем соообщении. К сожалению, строка так и отправилась с тегами, они не были интерпретированы ((. То есть я вижу, что мое сообщение имеет вид `<p>"что -то я тут пишу <a>моя сссылка</a>" </p>`
Когда форум автоматически присылает сообщения от админа, то там бывают ссылки, то есть по идее и у меня все должно работать.

Как в таком случае мне нужно было написать сообщение, чтобы добиться желаемого результата (вставить ссылку)?

Comment: Воообще рассылать спам ссылки по форумам это плохо! :)

Answer (score 1):

Грамотный форум, будет фильтровать все сообщения от пользователей, на наличие тегов и других подозрительных символов, которые, в прямых руках, могу натворить много лишнего.

***HTML теги***. Вот вы хотите ссылку туда засунуть. А появится умник и запихает туда целую таблицу с картинками звёзд из PlayBoy или еще чего по откровеннее, а **HTML5** и видео словит.

А насчет админа… ну что тут говорить. Он Бог своего творения, не ровняйте его возможности со своими.

Comment: Спасибо, да, я это понимаю. 
С технической т.з как можно решить было бы эту задачу - наверняка есть какие-то спец символы, кот можно обрамить теги , чтобы он не воспринимались как простая строка? (опустим случай, когда текст ким-то админским кодом фильтруется после отправки)

Comment: дайте ссылку на этот форум, если это возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Нормальные форумы частично поддерживают HTML теги в виде псевдо кода - так называемого BBCode. К примеру, код ссылки с его помощью будет выглядеть вот так:

```
[url=http://www.site-me.info/]Will code for food![/url]
```

__

подробней о BBCode на [русском языке](http://www.teosofia.ru/board/faq.php?mode=bbcode)